# SQL Server Error!(microsoft sql-dmo odbc sqlstate 42000 )

Tags: sql, sql-server

I m using SQL Server 2000. I can't backup my database. Its show me a error Message.this is below ...
[Error Image](http://img268.imageshack.us/i/dberror.png/)

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked in the SQL Server error log?

You are either out of space on that drive or do not have permission to write to it.

Answer (score 4):

status 112 means Insuficient Space on target disk. Free some space on the backup target (where the .bak is written).